# Field UserRole.Name does not exist

Tags: visualforce, formula

I have a field on the User object that users their Role's name to produce a text output.

When I try to reference this field in a visualforce page I get the titular error.

How can I reference this text field? Thanks!

Field BusinessUnit__c:

```
IF(CONTAINS( UserRole.Name , "Uno"), "Sales", 
IF(CONTAINS(UserRole.Name, "Dos"), "Sales", 
IF(CONTAINS(UserRole.Name, "Tres"), "Support", 
IF(CONTAINS(UserRole.Name, "CEO"), "Exec", 

"Shared"))))
```

Visualforce:

```
  <apex:outputLink value="/00O38000004hhNw?pv0={!$User.BusinessUnit__c}" id="theLink">
```

Error:

> Error: Field UserRole.Name does not exist. Check spelling

Comment: So it lets you save the formula?

Comment: Yes, the formula field is saved on the User and produces the expected output.

Comment: I could try this a field update to a text field on user obj when updated but that is not really satisfactory.

Comment: Yeah WFR might be your best bet unfortunately.

Comment: It is working via a text field, that I update via WFR. Seems like a bug in SF!

Comment: Yes I agree, but if you are looking to work around the issue with minimal effort, that's probably the path of least resistance.

Comment: Argh - spaces and the & sign in the textfield are causing issues with the filter, it only catches the first word

Comment: Just edited to a contains filter and ok

Comment: You can try `URLENCODE` to handle space as contains might break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the Formula field on the User object to a text field which is updated via workflow rule field update.
Then the text field is referenced in the visualforce page and it works.
Related bug? https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYtnQAG

Comment: I'd say it's unrelated to that Known Issue actually, since you were able to save the formula. There might be *another* KI for it, but I haven't checked.